# Ending a sentence then beginning a sentence with the same word. Quotation marks?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

### If you end a sentence, then begin the next sentence with the same word, but you wish to write more about that word in the next sentence, do you need to put that word in quotation marks in the next sentence?

Example:

Heavy machinery makes up the vast bulk of your vehicle's mass. "Mass," which alone, creates a significant hazard at high speeds.

or:

Heavy machinery makes up the vast bulk of your vehicle's mass. Mass, which alone, creates a significant hazard at high speeds.

Comment: “We had turkey for dinner.   Dinner was at 4 PM.”   Please [edit] your question to make the title less misleading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a NARQ.

Comment: Why do you need any quotation marks? What is the source of that information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latter is correct, though usually you try to avoid redundancy like that. A better way of writing your quote would be something like “Heavy machinery makes up the bulk of your vehicle’s mass, which alone creates a significant hazard at high speeds,” or “Heavy machinery makes up the bulk of your vehicle’s mass, and this alone creates a significant hazard at high speed.”